# Oracle 12c connection error:-Got minus one from a read call

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

My Sql developer was working fine from long time, suddenly from yesterday when i am trying to reconnect it is giving me following error:-

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: Got minus one from a read call, connect lapse 62991 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms.
```

[image]

**Things I tried to solve the issue:-**

1. Made corresponding changes in `sqlnet.ora` , `listener.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` files
2. Checked is there are too many open connections to the database service.
3. Restarted ORACLE service and listener
4. Firewall related changes
5. Reinstalled ORACLE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to approach a "Got minus one from a read call" error when connecting to an Amazon RDS Oracle instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660336/how-to-approach-a-got-minus-one-from-a-read-call-error-when-connecting-to-an-a)

Comment: Thank you for the link, but i have already tried that one.

Comment: It would help if you would edit your post to add information about what you have tried already and ruled out as possible reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the issue, it is due to a malware. Whenever i am trying to connect to DB port, it was automatically getting changed by malware.

You can also identify the problem by using `lsnrctl status` command, for further information. You can also see the log file of listener.

Run a full scan on your machine and restart listener, hope that helps.

Comment: Thankyou! I faced the same issue. Now its resolved. You saved my day! :D

Comment: how do u restart the listener