# Found issue in java application connecting with oracle database,SQLException: Io exception: Got minus one from a read call ,how I can solve it?

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, ioexception, sqlexception

I wrote a servlet application in my eclipse IDE,
I'm using,

- Tomcat v9.0.
- java1.8
- Oracle11g

My Oracle Username and Password is `scott` and `scott`.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","scott","scott");
```

While running this application I found bellow Output,

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Got minus one from a read call
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:111)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:145)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:386)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:413)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:164)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:34)
...
```

How I can solve this problem?
Please help me..

Comment: Refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660336/how-to-approach-a-got-minus-one-from-a-read-call-error-when-connecting-to-an-a

Comment: What version of Oracle database and what version of the Oracle JDBC driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved, there was a problem in Oracle listener.
My listener wasn't active.