# How to access to the oracle database from mac

Tags: java, sql, oracle, macos, containers

Im trying to access to oracle database to do the JDBC on my mac, and to perform such Im using containers (Dockers) [I have never used before] , however when Im trying to connect through the database by SQL developer, I got that error;

```
Se ha producido un error al realizar la operación solicitada:

Error de E/S: Got minus one from a read call

Código de proveedor 17002
```

Comment: This will probably answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660336/how-to-approach-a-got-minus-one-from-a-read-call-error-when-connecting-to-an-a

Comment: `docker ps` to show what container is running and what localhost:port maps to the TNS port within the container, then use that local port in your connection settings.