# SQLDeveloper throwing error "Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: Got minus one from a read call"

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

While Connecting database 11g using sqlDeveloper getting "Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: Got minus one from a read call" Error.

My other teammates are able to connect with the same version of sql Developer. This shows no change at database server and somewhere issue locally.

Kindly provide any solution to get rid off.

Comment: there are many posts here on stackoverflow discussing this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to approach a "Got minus one from a read call" error when connecting to an Amazon RDS Oracle instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660336/how-to-approach-a-got-minus-one-from-a-read-call-error-when-connecting-to-an-a)